# access pandas dataframe from another file while it is still being updated

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

consider a dataframe that is constantly being appended new values at given interval (say, every 10 mins) over a specific length of time (say, 300 mins). Whilst data is being added to this dataframe, I want to simultaneously be able to read this dataframe in another file [meaning perform some further process/analytics on the dataframe values from another .py file]. How can I achieve this? I suspect, that i need to use the multiprocessing or multi-treading library, but can I read the dataframe from memory or do i have to first write it to the disk and read the stored file?

Also, how can i run the first file (which appends the data) in the background so as to be able to work on other files from ipython shell ( i am using spyder 3.3 and python 2.7)

I did some online reading on multiprocessing but couldn't understand how to go about the two issues referred above. Generally, any pointers on how this can be achieved in simplest possible way will be helpful

Comment: If new values are appended only every ten minutes, why not read the dataframe into another file after the append finishes? That is, why not read the file in when you aren't appending? Does this writing and reading have to be done simultaneously? It seems like doing this reading and writing row-by-row is wasteful.

Comment: sorry..if this was not clear, but by 'read this dataframe in another file' i meant ability to further query this dataframe from another .py file. for example, perform some analytics on this dataframe values.

Comment: you may want to consider using something like blaze instead, and use a database as the backend (which you can append and read concurrently).

Comment: Had kind of the same idea to hold a dataframe as kind of cache in memory. Looks like this is not the common way (but would be a good one for very fast execution - most likely)